# c# how I can innerText in geckoWebbrowser without value

Tags: c#

this is the code :

```
<div id=":3d.f" class="df b-K b-K-Xb URaP8 editable" contenteditable="true" g_editable="true" role="textbox" aria-labelledby="177"></div>
```

in webBrowser I used this code

```
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("s").InnerText = "asdasd";
```

but I want use in `geckoWebBrowser`

please help me

thanks for all

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
GeckoHtmlElement myElement = null;
GeckoDocument myDoc = GeckowebBrowser.Window.Document;                        
myElement = myDoc.GetHtmlElementById("id_of_the_element");

if (myElement != null)
{
   myElement.InnerHtml = "inner html text";
}
```

Comment: thnx G siry but showed Error Mesg : convert Gecko.GeckoDOMdoucment to Gecko.Geckodoucment